# Spring queryForList not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-jdbc

I have the following query and the following piece of code to get the results.

```
    List<Map<String, Object>> rows = this.getBemsConnection().queryForList(ItemWorkflowDetails.BEMS_CREATION_DATE_QUERY, new Object[]{itemName});
        if (rows != null && !rows.isEmpty()) {
            for (Map<String, Object> row : rows) {
                itemSetupObj.setBemsCreation((String) row.get("BEMS_CREATION"));
                LOGGER.info("Bems Creation Date: {}", itemSetupObj.getBemsCreation());
            }
        }


    String BEMS_CREATION_DATE_QUERY = "SELECT creation_date bems_creation FROM xxref_cg1_o.mtl_system_items_b WHERE segment1 = ? AND organization_id = 1";
```

I am getting data for this from the backend database but nothing happens when I execute the query in Java. Am I missing something?

Comment: a comma between creation_date and bems_creation? Any exception?

Comment: No, same query works. No exception. Just does nothing. Logger is not printed. Also, the missing comma denotes that the 'bems_creation' is the column alias of the actual column name.

Comment: ok, if you don't get any exception, then maybe you are not querying the datasource you think you are querying (maybe)

Comment: itemName doesn't match any items. Try like '%itemName%'.

Comment: could it be that you're simply getting an empty result?

Comment: Nope, the query with the same itemName in Oracle, works. And fetches data. Also, I have double checked my data source. Everything seems in order.

Comment: Is there any way we can print the query it executes?

Answer (score 0):

Figured the issue, the input from Java was going in small case where as the data was stored in upper case in the table. Plus the query I ran in DB had the value in upper case. So indeed, I was not getting data as it was not able to make a match.